# How can I use multiple MongoDB databases in a NestJS application, with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

## Overview

> **FYI** : I uploaded a complete project to [**GitHub**](https://github.com/mighty-sparrow/test-mongo-multi-cxn.git). Feel free to download and see for yourself.

I created this project to identify a problem with NestJS, Mongoose and MongoDB. At a high level, the problem is targeting multiple databases from within the project. It seems like NestJS wants to add the suffix `'Model'` somewhere in the process.

In my *actual* application, I am trying to ensure a document is uploaded to MongoDB (...which is easy enough). I have to do some transformation work on the documents later, like on a scheduled job. Once the job is complete, I want to store the transformed document in a separate *container*.

> I use the term *"container"* generically, here -- I don't care if it's a database or a collection in the same database.

I would prefer to not modify my data such that I am sticking with the easy route (which means everything goes in the generic `fs.files` and `fs.documents` collections in the same database). I mean, the mechanisms are there and pretty well documented, so not sure why this vanilla example isn't working. Also, yes, I assumed that I would have to use two, separate databases since I don't imagine MongoDB (let alone Mongoose) provides the mechanisms for renaming those two collections. I am identifying the two, separate connections in the root `AppModule` as `firstCxn` and `secondCxn` so they can be referred to in their respective Module definitions.

### A Few Things I've Tried

- I thought there might be some kind of undocumented, explicit naming convention I was missing out on, so I went back and renamed the entities. I added `'Model'` to the ends of their names. That's when I started seeing this whole `'...ModelModel'` issue.
- When referencing the models in decorators, I used explicit string values where strings are allowed. For example, in the `first.server.ts`, I added  `@InjectModel('First')` instead of  `@InjectModel(FirstModel.name)`.
- Added a reference to the `FirstModel` class in the `FirstModule` definition, right before the `MongooseModule.forFeature(...)`.

  - This seemed to provide some forward progress. Well...at least, when I changed it in the `FirstModule`, I started getting the same error for the `SecondModule`.

### Error Output

This is what I get as the output in my debug console...

```
Debugger attached.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
(node:27751) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.                                                                                                                                                                  
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Nest] 27751  - 12/11/2023, 2:57:23 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[Nest] 27751  - 12/11/2023, 2:57:23 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] SecondModel dependencies initialized +41ms                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Nest] 27751  - 12/11/2023, 2:57:23 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +0ms                                                                                                                                                                                
[Nest] 27751  - 12/11/2023, 2:57:23 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +0ms                                                                                                                                                                                
[Nest] 27751  - 12/11/2023, 2:57:23 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FirstsService (?). Please make sure that the argument "FirstModelModel" at index [0] is available in the FirstModule context.
```

> It seems that NestJS is looking for something with an additional `'Model'` at the end of the name.

---

## Questions

1. Has anyone seen this before?

   - ...anything obvious jumping out?
2. Are there any *good* examples of using NestJS, Mongo and Mongoose with multiple databases/collections out there?

> #### Bonus Questions
>
> 3. If teflon is so awesome, why does *it* stick to the pan?
> 4. Will the Sonny ever get some Trix? ...is Sonny still even alive?
> 5. If a duck eats lunch and then goes swimming right away, does it get a cramp?

Answer (score 1):

## [Insert `:facepalm:` HERE]

Looks like what I was glossing over as a kind of "belt and suspenders" approach is actually just *"the approach"*.

When injecting the model name in `@InjectModel`, it is absolutely required to specify the connection name there as well. So, my code looks like this:

```
constructor(
    @InjectModel(FirstModel.name, 'firstCxn')
    private firstModel: Model<FirstModel>,
  ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> **Yes**, we can used multiple mongoose databases in nestjs application.
> but nestjs is the first mongoose import considered as a database and ignores the second mongoose import database link.
> ```

```
The Below code is nestjs for multiple Mongoose database uses:-

app.module.ts

    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DB_URL, {
          dbName: 'atlas_db',
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/',{
          dbName:'local_db'
        })


    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([
        { name: Job.name, schema: JobSchema },
        { name: Local.name, schema: LocalSchema }
      ])],
```

Comment: You can use multiple databases one is MySQL and the second one is MongoDB.
and you can save data in MySQL entity and mongoose schema and also get all data.